# How to read structured data from file in C++?

Tags: c++, file-io

I have a data file where I need to read a datum from each line and store it. And then depending on the value of one of those datums store that data in an array so that I can then calculate the median value of all of these data.

The line of data is demographic information and depending on the geographic location, address of a person. I need to capture their age and then find the median of the people that live on a particular street for example.

So the data set is 150,000 records and each record has 26 fields, a lot of those fields are segments of an address and then the other fields are just numbers, age, street number and that sort of thing.

So what I need to do is read through the line and then if a particular field in the record meets a certain condition I need to capture a field from the record and store it in an array so that I can calculate the median of people that live on "Oak Street" for example.

I have the conditional logic and can work the sort out but I'm uncomfortable with the iostream objects in C++, like instantiating an ifstream object and then reading from the file itself.

Oh I forgot that the data was a comma separated value file.

Comment: What part of that are you having trouble with?

Comment: also give us more detail about the file format, input expected output

Comment: I was trying to create small ad hoc solutions for work on my own :)

Comment: would you be willing to try perl? reading in a file a line at a time and pulling out fields based on conditions is very straightforward in perl.

Comment: I would be willing to learn perl but to be honest I know nothing about the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For comma-delimited input:

```
using namespace std;
ifstream file;
string line;
while(getline(file, line)) {
    istringstream stream(line);
    string data[3];
    for(int ii = 0; ii < sizeof data / sizeof data[0]; ++ii)
        if(!getline(stream, data[ii], ','))
            throw std::runtime_error("invalid data");
    // process data here
}
```

For whitespace-delimited input (original answer):

```
using namespace std;
ifstream file;
string line;
while(getline(file, line)) {
    int datum1;
    string datum2;
    double datum3;
    istringstream stream(line);
    if(!(line >> datum1 >> datum2 >> datum3))
        throw std::runtime_error("invalid data");
    // process data here
}
```

These methods won't win any prizes for performance, but hopefully they're fairly reliable and easy to understand.

Comment: Will `line >> datum1 >> datum2 >> datum3` work if the datums are comma separated ?

Comment: No, if the fields are separated by commas, see the second bit of code I'm posting now.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a perfect problem for an SQL light style embedded data base.  Then you could have any number of standard SQL features without having to rewrite the wheel.

Comment: Does SQL have a high learning curve?  I work full-time and go to school full-time and I'm not currently learning SQL in any of my classes but I could try to fit it in on the side.

Comment: Not for what you are looking at doing.

Comment: I will have to look into SQL because I know that there is a lot of work that two guys do in the office with it but I'm not sure how proficient they are in it so if I can get up to speed a little bit I may be able to help them out.